# What do Apple Diagnostics for Mac offer better than Apple Service Providers' tests?

Tags: mac, apple-hardware-test, apple-diagnostics

Apple's embedded tests for Macs seem very shallow compared to those used by Apple Service Providers (AST2 tests).

I know AST2 tests are very good at catching sensor failures (such as temperature, voltage and current sensors), are the embedded tests as capable?

I wonder if these tests are programmed in a hidden partition, in the firmware or they're downloaded from the cloud.

Comment: Since you've written "*get opinions*" in the post, I must cast a close vote. But seriously though, could you reduce it down to say, what results do they offer etc.?

Comment: I extended it a bit, I hope it's OK with you.

Comment: Agree with @ankii.  If there's a specific test with a specific question, that will help prevent it from being closed.  If you keep the question too general, it risks downvotes and/or closure.

Comment: I tried to service this a bit, but it needs more work than I'm comfortable doing when I'm not the OP. @Antonio23249, I _think_ what you really want to know is: "What is the difference between Apple's Embedded Tests and the AST2 tests used by Apple Service Providers?" If I'm right, try structuring the question around that title.

Answer (score 2):

One of your wonderments is where the tests are actually stored. They're not in a hidden partition nor downloaded from the cloud, they're located in the firmware on the main board.

The included, automatic tests are not as comprehensive as those that can be performed by Apple Service Providers.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, good to know those tests are on the firmware.  Sorry I didn't word my question more clearly.  My idea (please correct me if I'm wrong):
- HDD/SSD tests aren't extended ones, just basic ones (not sure if the older AHT offers extended tests)
- Memory tests are also short tests.
- Testing for voltage/current/temperature sensors? no idea if they're complete or not.